# Split string in between 2 delimiters and include them

Tags: javascript, regex

Giving the following string...

```
"Here is my very _special string_ with {different} types of _delimiters_ that might even {repeat a few times}."
```

... how to split it into an array using the 2 delimiters ("_", "{ and }") but also keeping the delimiters in each element of the array?

The goal is:

```
[
  "Here is my very ", 
  "_special string_", 
  " with ", 
  "{different}", 
  " types of ", 
  "_delimiters_", 
  "that might even ", 
  "{repeat a few times}", 
  "."
]
```

My best bet was:

```js
let myText = "Here is my very _special string_ with {different} types of _delimiters_ that might even {repeat a few times}."

console.log(myText.split(/(?=_|{|})/g))
```

as you see, it fails to reproduce the desirable array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
s.split(/(_[^_]*_|{[^{}]*})/).filter(Boolean)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UpBxaS/2). The whole pattern is enclosed in a capturing group, so all matching substrings are included in the resulting array after `String#split`.

**Regex details**

- `(_[^_]*_|{[^{}]*})` - Capturing group 1:

  - `_[^_]*_` - `_`, 0 or more chars other than `_` and then a `_`
  - `|` - or
  - `{[^{}]*}` - a `{`, then any 0 or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}`

See JS demo:

```js
var s = "Here is my very _special string_ with {different} types of _delimiters_ that might even {repeat a few times}.";
console.log(s.split(/(_[^_]*_|{[^{}]*})/).filter(Boolean));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following regex which returns some `undefined` values, finally, you can filter the `undefined` values.

```js
let myText = "Here is my very _special string_ with {different} types of _delimiters_ that might even {repeat a few times}."

console.log(myText.split(/(_.+?_)|({.+?})/g).filter(Boolean))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may split the string on (zero-width) matches of the following regular expression (with `filter(Boolean)`).

```
(?<= )(?=[_{])|(?<=[_}])(?=\W)
```

Note that this regex does not contain capture groups.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oKuePP/2/)

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<= )     preceding character is a space         (positive lookbehind)
(?=[_{])   following character is '_' or '{'      (positive lookahead) 
|          or 
(?<=[_}])  preceding character is '_' or '}'      (positive lookbehind)
(?=\W)     following character is a non-word char (positive lookahead)
```

`(?=\W)` may, for example, match a space or punctuation character.

I have assumed that braces and underscores are not nested (e.g., the string will not contain `_a {b} c_` or `{a _b_ c}`).

Answer (score -1):

I don't like regular expressions because I don't understand this kind of stuff.

So my solution is to replace blank_ with #_ and so on and split with #.